# is there a way to override -webkit-filter: blur in a child element?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to have my elements display on top of an image background with blur applied to it.

See http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Yr2zD/ for the reference.

```
<body>
<div class="bgImageContainer"></div>
<div class="content"> Some text and stuff here</div>
</body>
```

Now, i think that the second div should be nested inside the first one. But then the content becomes blurred as well, and i can't find a way to disable blur in the "content" element. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If the element is a child then you can not override it. Same with `opacity` on a parent will make everything inside of it transparent as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr2zD/615/)

```
    <body>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="bgImageContainer"></div>
        <div class="content"> Some text and stuff here</div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Unfortunately, you cannot target just the background image in CSS3. The way to do this is to wrap everything as siblings, but the blurred element definitely needs to be a sibling of the non blurred element. Any child of the blurred element will be blurred. Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the point of wrapping those two divs if there is nothing applied to wrap? Also, why do you redefine position attribute twice? Could you explain what is the conceptual difference with my original fiddle?

Comment: The only thing this does is allow those to have a parent. In my eyes, it's better to at least have a parent but it is not needed.

Comment: As Josh says, it's just better form, but no need. Position attribute was a mistake. I've corrected this.